# Is there a possibility to invite a GitHub User in a organization with the GitHub-API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, github, account

i need for my Javascript-Code to invite a GitHub User in my organisation. Is this possible with the GitHub API and how?
Thank you :)

Comment: Search for "github api invite" seems to bring up the api documentation

Answer (score 0):

From [the API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#add-a-member):

> To add someone as a member to an organization, you must [invite them to the organization](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#add-or-update-organization-membership) or [invite them to a team](https://developer.github.com/v3/teams/members/#add-or-update-team-membership).

You can invite a user to an organization by inviting them to a team. This can be achieved by doing a PUT request to `/teams/:team_id/memberships/:username`. See more on this in [the docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/teams/members/#add-or-update-team-membership).